# How to diagonalise this free fermionic Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fermions

I have the following $1$D fermionic Hamiltonian $H$, given by
$$
H = H^A_0+H
_0^B+H_I^{AB}=\sum_{jk\in A} H_{jk}^Ac^\dagger_j c_k + \sum_{jk\in B} H_{jk}^Bc^\dagger_j c_k  + \lambda \sum_{j\in A, \ k \in B} H^{AB}_{jk} (c^\dagger_j c_k+ c_k^\dagger c_j),
$$
i.e. two independent fermionic subsystems “interacting” via some $H_I^{AB}$, the $H_{jk}$’s could be whatever, I’m just interested in the above form. I know I could gather everything together into one big $H_{jk}$, diagonalise it, define some new $c_j=\sum_n \phi^n_j d_n$ such that $H=\sum_n \epsilon_n d^\dagger_n d_n$ and call it a day. The problem is that I would loose track of $\lambda$ , a parameter I want to tweak later on as it modulates the strength of the subsystem’s interaction.

**How can one diagonalise $H$ keeping track of $\lambda$?**

Comment: The Hamiltonian is one-particle, but written in second quantization. It is not clear what you mean by loosing track of $\lambda$, since it will enter the new energies and the coefficients $\phi_j^n$.

Comment: Are you interested in perturbation theory in $\lambda$ or specifically in exact solutions?

Comment: It seems a double-1d lattice. The interaction is adjacent or long range?

Comment: @RogerVadim indeed $\lambda$ will enter in the energies and eigenvectors. What I meant is that, aside from the final form, I don't know how $\lambda$ will explicitly enter the solution.

Comment: @Youran a priori long range, i.e. all to all. But can relax that condition if it simplifies things.

Comment: @jacob1729 , for the moment exact solutions only.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian It depends on the structure of your Hamiltonian - you have to diagonamize a block-diagonal matrix with non-diagonal blocks proportional to $\lambda$. It is hard to be more specific than that without additional constraints on $H_{ij}^\alpha$.

Comment: @RogerVadim , I am being vague because I don't really care about the specifics of the $H_{ij}$s. If you know of any example where this has been solved I would also be happy with that. I just want to study two systems of free fermions that interact together with strength $\lambda$.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian The simplest example is a two level system: each subsystem has one level and they are coupled with strength $\lambda$

Comment: Roger Vadim's comments seem spot on. If there is some structure (e.g. if H_{ij}s are translation invariant so that you can Fourier transform and reduce the matrix dimension) you may get somewhere, otherwise it's probably most promising to just study the system numerically for different values of $\lambda$.

Comment: @Anyon can you have an interaction between the two subsystems that is translationally invariant?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Depends on the system. I don't know what geometry you have in mind. It's possible in bipartite lattices, but if you just have two isolated clusters, probably not.

Comment: @Anyon thank you so much for your insights, I will try with a bipartite lattice (I'm guessing that would just be a layer on top of the other) and see if I can manage to solve it.

Comment: You could for example try a ladder, where you call one leg $A$ and the other $B$. The simplest interaction between the two sublattices is then a coupling across the rungs, but you can add longer-range ones too. If the interaction strengths don't depend on the location along the leg you have translational invariance and may treat momentum along the ladder as a good quantum number.

Comment: @Anyon do you mean something like $H=J_A \sum_{j\in A} c^\dagger_j c_j + J_B \sum_{j\in B} c^\dagger_j c_j + \lambda \sum_{j} (c^\dagger_{j\in A}c_{j \in B}+h.c.)$ or the more general $H=J_A \sum_{jk\in A} H^A_{jk}c^\dagger_j c_k + J_B \sum_{j\in B} H^B_{jk} c^\dagger_j c_k + \lambda \sum_{j} (c^\dagger_{j\in A} c_{j\in B}+h.c.)$ ? Because I don’t know how I would tackle the latter one. Another one could be nearest-neighbours interaction with ladders with the same ladder-ladder interaction as above.

Comment: You probably want to allow hopping along the legs, right? The first option only seems to have some on-site chemical potential terms. In the second option, the summation is handled inconsistently in the first two terms. Maybe it's just a typo? The first ladder model I'd try for this exercise is the nearest neighbor version $H=J_A\sum_jc_j^\dagger c_{j+1}+J_B\sum_jd_j^\dagger d_{j+1}+\lambda\sum_j\left( c_j^\dagger d_j+h.c.\right)$ where $j$ labels the position along the leg, $c_j$ ($d_j$) annihilates a fermion at site $j$ on leg A (B), and $J_{A/B}$ is real.

Comment: @Anyon , yes that’s a small typo (I cant edit it anymore). I have created a new question for the nearest neighbour version as I am struggling to diagonalise the interaction part (at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644388/254500 ). My problem is that on the momentum basis, i.e. $f_{k,A} \propto \sum_j e^{ikj}c_{k,A}$, the interaction doesnt arrive at a diagonal form. It remains like $$ \sum_j(c^\dagger_{j,A}c_{j,B} +h.c.) \rightarrow \sum_k (c^\dagger_{k,A}c_{k,B} +h.c.),$$ which isn't diagonal (it’s anti-diagonal).

Comment: A lattice with two identical atoms in a unit cell would suffice - e.g., graphene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamiltonian you give is ***completely general***. There is no restriction whatsoever, even if you set $\lambda=1$. Thus, there cannot be any special structure in the way you diagonalize it (or on $\lambda$, as you can absorb $\lambda$ in $H^{AB}$), unless you give exttra information.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess my other post ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644388/solution-of-a-free-fermionic-ladder ) and your helpful answer clarifies things a lot.